# Autorotate option for GenericMultipleBarcodeReader in Zxing.Net

Tags: c#, zxing

How can I set the hint 'AutoRotate' for 'GenericMultipleBarcodeReader' in Zxing.net. I have set Try_Harder = true. But no results for detecting multiple 1d/2d barcodes from a rotated image. If the image is aligned properly it gives the results.

Edit: In 'GenericMultipleBarcodeReader' I am using 'ByQuadrantReader'. This could detect barcodes and QR codes from properly aligned images. For a rotated image it could not find anything.

```
MultiFormatReader multiReader = new MultiFormatReader();
ZXing.Multi.GenericMultipleBarcodeReader byquadReader = new ZXing.Multi.GenericMultipleBarcodeReader(new ByQuadrantReader(multiReader));              
Dictionary<DecodeHintType, object> hints = new Dictionary<DecodeHintType, object>();
hints.Add(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, true);
List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
formats.Add(BarcodeFormat.All_1D);
formats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
hints.Add(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, formats);
****
byquadresults = byquadReader.decodeMultiple(binaryBitmap, hints);
```

Could any one please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutoRotate can only be used with the BarcodeReader class.

```
     var bitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("<path to your image file>");
     var reader = new BarcodeReader
     {
        AutoRotate = true,
        Options = new DecodingOptions
        {
           TryHarder = true,
           PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>
           {
              BarcodeFormat.All_1D,
              BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
           }
        }
     };

     var results = reader.DecodeMultiple(bitmap);
```

If you want to use the ByQuadrantReader you have to replace the line

```
var reader = new BarcodeReader...
```

with

```
var reader = new BarcodeReader(new ByQuadrantReader(new MultiFormatReader()), null, null)...
```