# What changes are required to make this class scan Barcode in any direction. It works only for QR codes

Tags: android-studio, zxing, offline, barcode-scanner, android-camerax

I am developing a Qr Code and Barcode Scanner App, using CameraX and Zxing but the following class only works for Qr Code. I want to scan barcodes as well from any orientation on an android device

**Code Scanning class:**

```
 public class QRCodeImageAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
        private QRCodeFoundListener listener;

    public QRCodeImageAnalyzer(QRCodeFoundListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    @Override
    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {

        Image image = imageProxy.getImage();
       if (image.getFormat() == YUV_420_888 || image.getFormat() == YUV_422_888 || image.getFormat() == YUV_444_888) {
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] imageData = new byte[byteBuffer.capacity()];
            byteBuffer.get(imageData);

            PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(
                    imageData,
                    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                    0, 0,
                    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                    false
            );

            BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

            try {
                Result result = new QRCodeMultiReader().decode(binaryBitmap);
                listener.onQRCodeFound(result.getText());
            } catch (FormatException | ChecksumException | NotFoundException e) {
                listener.qrCodeNotFound();
            }
        }

        imageProxy.close();
    }

}
```

**I also tried this class CameraX with MLKit:** I tried the sample from the official docs of MLKit provided in the first answer but it scan nothing neither QR Code nor Barcode. Please take a look if I put things the wrong way.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.util.Log
import androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.Barcode
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScannerOptions
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage

@UseExperimental(markerClass = [ExperimentalGetImage::class])
class QrCodeAnalyzer(

    private val onQrCodesDetected: (qrCodes: List<Barcode>?) -> Unit
) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    private  val TAG: String = "Kamran"
    private fun rotationDegreesToFirebaseRotation(rotationDegrees: Int): Int {
        return when (rotationDegrees) {
            0 -> 0
            90 -> 1
            180 -> 2
            270 -> 3
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Not supported")
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
        val rotation = rotationDegreesToFirebaseRotation(image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

        image.image?.let{

            val optionss = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
                .setBarcodeFormats(
                    Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_EAN_8,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_EAN_13)
                .build()

            val imageValue = InputImage.fromMediaImage(it, image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)


            //val options = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder().setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE).build()
            val scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(optionss)

            scanner.process(imageValue)
                .addOnCompleteListener { barcodes ->
                    barcodes.result?.forEach { barcode ->
                        val bounds = barcode.boundingBox
                        val corners = barcode.cornerPoints

                        val rawValue = barcode.rawValue
                    }
                    onQrCodesDetected(barcodes.result)
                    image.image?.close()
                    image.close()
                    Log.d(TAG, "Successfully got inside onCompleteListener")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { failure ->
                    failure.printStackTrace()
                    image.image?.close()
                    image.close()
                }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it because you are using the QRCodeMultiReader() class that can only read QRcodes? Why not find a class that can read anything like this article and change it? [Read multiple barcodes from single image file using Zxing library in java service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377223/9014308)

Comment: Or it seems that AutoRotate can be used with the BarcodeReader class in C#. Why not find out if you can do the same with Android Java? [Autorotate option for GenericMultipleBarcodeReader in Zxing.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40400935/9014308)

Comment: Can you please provide the Exact code in Answer, I am a beginner and it is hard for me to put things together. It would be a great favor It's been weeks I am stuck on this. Thank you Sir!

Comment: Unfortunately, I just searched and found it, and I have no knowledge or experience of Android or ZXing, so I can not show the source code. So please check it out based on the content of the article introduced.

Comment: Ok sir, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If using ZXing android library is a requirement (afaik it is no longer developed). If it is not a hard requirement, I would suggest you to give it a try for MLKit Barcode Scanner. It scans QR as well.
Also, you would probably find it easier to implement with CameraX as they already have multiple examples and sample code.
For example check [this guide](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android) for step by step instructions.
Particularly [this part](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android#using-a-media.image).

You can configire the scanner first:

```
val options = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
        .setBarcodeFormats(
                Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE,
                Barcode.FORMAT_EAN_8,
                Barcode.FORMAT_EAN_13)
        .build()
```

then;

```
private class YourImageAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
        if (mediaImage != null) {
            val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
            // Pass image to an ML Kit Vision API
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

finally this is how you get it decoded:

```
val result = scanner.process(image)
        .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
            // Task completed successfully
            // ...
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            // Task failed with an exception
            // ...
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean with no use ? can you elaborate more? Did you follow the steps in the guide ? What didn't work?

Comment: see the second class, I tried this but nothing scanned.